# Resources utilization summary for interval of time using UNIX command

Tags: unix, memory-management, command-line, resources

I have a Unix server box , i need to generate Resource utilization report for this server from (1-1-2012 to today ) how i can do that ?

Example of report parameter :

```
Memory size
Memory free size
Memory used size
Virtual Memory size
average Memory size
average Memory free size
average Memory used size
average Virtual Memory size
```

the same for CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [vmstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat) and [sar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sar_%28Unix%29) commands.